# Has anyone experience issues with duplicated text while using Trafilatura?

Tags: python, html, parsing, xml-parsing, scrape

Running into duplication issues when trying to use `trafilatura` to scrape the following webpage, even when I set `deduplicate=True`. Does anyone know if this is a shortcoming of the package or if there are any parameters I can toggle to get rid of this behavior?

https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcminutes20200429.htm

```
import trafilatura

downloaded = trafilatura.fetch_url(url)
text = trafilatura.extract(downloaded, target_language='en', include_tables=True, deduplicate=True)
```

**Output:**

Full text is too long to quote here but a couple of duplicate fragments:

```
**Notation Vote**
By notation vote completed on May 19, 2020, the Committee unanimously approved the minutes of the Committee meeting held on April 28–29, 2020.
Notation Vote
By notation vote completed on May 19, 2020, the Committee unanimously approved the minutes of the Committee meeting held on April 28–29, 2020.
```

```
**Staff Economic Outlook**
The projection for the U.S. economy prepared by the staff for the June FOMC meeting was downgraded, on balance, as compared with the April meeting forecast in response to information on the spread of the coronavirus and changes in the measures undertaken to contain it both at home and abroad, along with incoming economic data. U.S. real GDP was forecast to show a historically large decline in the second quarter of this year, and the unemployment rate was expected to be sharply higher than in the first quarter. The substantial fiscal policy measures and appreciable support from monetary policy, along with the Federal Reserve's liquidity and lending facilities, were expected to help mitigate the deterioration in current economic conditions and to help boost the recovery.
Staff Economic Outlook
The projection for the U.S. economy prepared by the staff for the June FOMC meeting was downgraded, on balance, as compared with the April meeting forecast in response to information on the spread of the coronavirus and changes in the measures undertaken to contain it both at home and abroad, along with incoming economic data. U.S. real GDP was forecast to show a historically large decline in the second quarter of this year, and the unemployment rate was expected to be sharply higher than in the first quarter. The substantial fiscal policy measures and appreciable support from monetary policy, along with the Federal Reserve's liquidity and lending facilities, were expected to help mitigate the deterioration in current economic conditions and to help boost the recovery.
```

Comment: I've checked and it looks like there is no issues with trafilatura library in this case. Content of web page depends on site owners.